# How to change the color bar of chart bars obtained with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data with samples of three categories.

With the ggplot2 it is possible to obtain a good bar plot representation.

However, I need also change the color of each category by colors as darkorange2, dodgerblue2, and firebrick2.

I trying to use the function, *scale_fill_manual*, but I always seem to obtain errors.

An example of my current plot without changes in the colors is:

```
require(ggplot2)
d.f<-data.frame(v=c("a","a","b","c","c"),x=sample(LETTERS,5),y=10+runif(5))

pbar <- ggplot(data=d.f, aes(x=x, y=y,fill=v)) +  
         geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.8) + 
         theme(text= element_text(size=16, family = "Times New Roman"),
               axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust=1, vjust = 0, face="italic", colour="black"),
               axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black")) +  
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.0,12)) + 
         scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +  
         theme(aspect.ratio = 0.8) + 
         xlab("Sample")+ylab("Abundance")

pbar<-pbar+theme(axis.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
pbar<-pbar+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16))
pbar
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have tried with `scale_fill_manual` to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize a vector mapping all of the values in `v` to colors and use it in `scale_fill_manual`:

```
require(ggplot2)
d.f<-data.frame(v=c("a","a","b","c","c"),x=c("A","C","T","S","G"),y=10+runif(5))
cols <- c("a"="darkorange2","b"="dodgerblue2", "c"="firebrick2")

pbar <- ggplot(data=d.f, aes(x=x, y=y,fill=v)) +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.8) + 
  theme(text= element_text(size=16, family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust=1, vjust = 0, face="italic", colour="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black")) +  
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.0,12)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +  
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.8) + 
  xlab("Sample")+ylab("Abundance") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)

pbar<-pbar+theme(axis.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
pbar<-pbar+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16))
pbar
```

[image]